# Why does this goroutine not call wg.Done()?

Tags: go, concurrency, synchronization, channel

Suppose there are a maximum two elements (worker addresses) on registerChan at any point. Then for some reason, the following code does not call wg.Done() in the last two goroutines.

```
func schedule(jobName string, mapFiles []string, nReduce int, phase jobPhase, registerChan chan string) {
    var ntasks int
    var nOther int // number of inputs (for reduce) or outputs (for map)
    switch phase {
    case mapPhase:
        ntasks = len(mapFiles)
        nOther = nReduce
    case reducePhase:
        ntasks = nReduce
        nOther = len(mapFiles)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Schedule: %v %v tasks (%d I/Os)\n", ntasks, phase, nOther)

    const rpcname = "Worker.DoTask"
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for taskNumber := 0; taskNumber < ntasks; taskNumber++ {
        file := mapFiles[taskNumber%len(mapFiles)]
        taskArgs := DoTaskArgs{jobName, file, phase, taskNumber, nOther}
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(taskArgs DoTaskArgs) {
            workerAddr := <-registerChan
            print("hello\n")
            // _ = call(workerAddr, rpcname, taskArgs, nil)
            registerChan <- workerAddr
            wg.Done()
        }(taskArgs)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Printf("Schedule: %v done\n", phase)
}
```

If I put `wg.Done()` before `registerChan <- workerAddr` it works just fine and I have no idea why. I have also tried deferring wg.Done() but that doesn't seem to work even though I expected it to. I think I have some misunderstanding of how go routines and channels work which is causing my confusion.

Comment: When you start this function, there is a maximum of two worker addresses in the channel, but if you consume one, is there somewhere else where you add in the channel ? If so, the channel could be full when you want to add the worker address again, this will block.

Comment: You should come up with a well focused, runnable example that shows the behavior. You problem probably has nothing to do at all with sync.Workgroups but with bad syncronisation and blocking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it **stopped** here:

```
workerAddr := <-registerChan
```

For a buffered channel:
To get this `workerAddr := <-registerChan` to work: the channel `registerChan`  must have a value; otherwise, **the code will stop here waiting for the channel**.

---

I managed to run your code this way (try [this](https://play.golang.org/p/aqsWVntjZ7O)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    registerChan := make(chan int, 1)
    for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go fn(i, registerChan)
    }
    registerChan <- 0 // seed
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(<-registerChan)
}

func fn(taskArgs int, registerChan chan int) {
    workerAddr := <-registerChan
    workerAddr += taskArgs
    registerChan <- workerAddr
    wg.Done()
}

var wg sync.WaitGroup
```

Output:

```
55
```

Explanation:
This code adds 1 to 10 using a channel and 10 goroutines plus one main goroutine.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you run this statement `registerChan <- workerAddr`, if the channel capacity is full you cannot add in it and it will block. If you have a pool of, say 10, workerAddr, you could add all of them in a buffered channel of capacity 10 before calling `schedule`. Do not add after the call, to guarantee that if you take a value from the channel, there is space to add it again after. Using `defer` at the beginning of your goroutine is good.